Is it possible for the changelist placeholder (in version tag) to be automatically resolved by the Maven release plugin?
I have multi-module project:

module-parent
module-A
module-B

I need to have branch name auto-inserted in maven artifact version (when deploy) and ignore it (when release). To achieve this goal I use changelist placeholder.
To make it work I followed instruction for multi-module setup:
https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html
It works with deploy, eg. for DEV branch:
mvn -Dchangelist=-DEV clean deploy ...
1.0.0${changelist}-SNAPSHOT (pom.xml) will be artifact version: 1.0.0-DEV-SNAPSHOT
changelist placeholder is present in <parent><version> tag (module-A and module-B) and in <version> tag in module-parent.
When I try to release project, I get the error:
Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
    org.example:module-parent:pom:1.0.0${changelist}-SNAPSHOT
in project 'module-A' (org.example:module-A:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)

I need it work in a way that I would have versions (eg. branch DEV):
mvn ${someArgs} -Dchangelist= release:prepare release:perform

1.0.0${changelist}-SNAPSHOT  (pom.xml)  =>   1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (artifact)   before release
1.0.0${changelist}           (pom.xml)  =>   1.0.0          (release artifact)
1.0.1${changelist}-SNAPSHOT  (pom.xml)  =>   1.0.1-SNAPSHOT (artifact)

It is essential that changelist placeholder should not be deleted after release.
I would like maven-release-plugin to replace changelist placeholder with given argument.
Is it possible or is any workaround. The goal is to have different versions for feature branches while developing applications, but release process should ignore changelist placeholder.
Similar questions:

Maven Release Plugin together with cifriendly versions
Add suffix in maven release plugin

I tried to run flatten:flatten goal before release:prepare goal but it didn't help and error is the same.
